# pipenv and conda in macOS

Tags: python, pip, conda

I use pip and pipenv to manage my python dependencies and packages in macOS. A package I need [(here)](https://github.com/IntelPython/mkl_fft) seems to only be available for install via Conda.

I would like to keep working with my usual workflow using pip/pipenv but install this package with conda without messing up my python environment.

For instance, I do not want to modify what python I am running.

Is there a good way to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always worth doing a check on pypi.org

```
https://pypi.org/project/mkl-fft/
```

installs from pip giving 1.0.6

Comment: I have downloaded the (wheel file)[ https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9c/cf/2a287c8021d458d5c3dafdd3550952cd875c257190ed91aaf55fa4758896/mkl_fft-1.0.6-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_12_intel.macosx_10_12_x86_64.whl] but when i run
`pip install --no-index --find-links=. mkl-fft` or `pip install mkl-fft-package.whl` I get the error
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mkl-fft
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for mkl-fft